# How can access SQL SERVER 2008 in local PC with only IP?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2008 already, but now I only can access by writing "PCNAME\SQL".
So what can I configure to can access SQL Server 2008 with only IP?

Comment: Sorry, who know where's the answer which I accepted yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

I supposed `SQL` is the `named instance` you have installed, right? so you cant access it only by using your IP, you need to infor the name of the instance. You should be able to do it by:

- your_ip\SQL
- 127.0.0.1\SQL
- localhost\SQL

if you have a default instance installed, you should be able to access using all the options above without the  `\SQL`

Answer (score 1):

First :

- Open Sql Server Configuration Manager
- Choose SQL Server NetWork Configuration
- Enable TCP/IP

Then Restart you SQL Server in SQL Server Service

Now you can connect to you SQL Server by IP : yourIp\SQL or yourIp or yourIp\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Thank you, out of all solutions your solution work for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have default instance installed you can just targeted with `.`/`localhost`/`127.0.0.1`/`yourip`.

If you have named instance you need to specify the name. i.e. `.\INSTANCE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

There are always numerous options to connect to a local installation of SQL Server:

`.`,
`localhost`,
`127.0.0.1`,
`(locaL)`.

There's more than that:

http://mssqlforum.com/posts/63/

If you installed an instance, you have to add that, though, as specified by Diego.